# How to "Turn off messages about Windows Backup" using command line/ powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, automation

[Turn off messages about windows Backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxHYY.png)I am working on a script that sets certain desired features on and off for a windows server. I need to enable - "Turn off messages about Windows Backup" in action center. I know one of the way is to make some changes  in the reg key but not able to make that work.

Comment: registry or group policy is going to be the only way it appears. Someone more knowledgeable may be able to prove me wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* don't want to (or can't) use GPO to set this, you have to set make sure the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup` key exists, and create (or update) a DWORD named `DisableMonitoring` with a value of 1.

To do this in Powershell:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup `
  -Name DisableMonitoring -PropertyType DWORD -Value 1
```

If the property already exists, you will get an error, and you can use the `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet instead, which is similar but omits the `-PropertyType` parameter:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup `
  -Name DisableMonitoring -Value 1
```

I'm not seeing this documented anywhere, but as with many other registry keys that can get set as part of a GPO, you may need to reboot before Windows will recognize it if updated in the registry directly.

To be clear though, **the recommended way to set this would be via either a local group policy or one pushed out as part of a domain policy**.

**EDIT**: Here is the official Microsoft documentation on that key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/backup/registry-keys-for-backup-and-restore#disablemonitoring. If this doesn't work, something else is going on but this is the correct programmatic solution.

**EDIT 2**: **This will *only* stop the popup** - if you want to disable the relevant screen you linked to in the Action Center, you will need to set the appropriate local or domain group policy setting so it becomes "Managed by your administrator" and greyed out.

If you ***really really really*** can't just set a domain policy and want to set the local policy setting Powershell, you can explore using the [PolicyFileEditor](https://github.com/dlwyatt/PolicyFileEditor) Powershell module, or set a local policy in your image (https://superuser.com would be a good place to ask how to retain a local group policy in a sysprepped Windows image).

Comment: I tried what you mentioned above. But its still the same even after the reboot. I have added the image in my question that showcases what I am asking about just in case to provide more clarity.

Comment: Let me ask this - with the registry setting set, do you get alerts (notifications) that it is not set up? Or do you only see it here, and are looking to prevent a user from configuring it?

Comment: Also, can you update your post with the version and edition of Windows you are running? (e.g. Windows Vista Home, Windows 7 Pro, etc.)

Comment: I am running Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: And are you still getting the taskbar popups about this? Or are you only seeing this in the Action Center?

Comment: I have not seen the taskbar popups though. I just see it in the Action Center.

Comment: Then the registry key is doing its job. If you want to disable the function entirely in the Action Center, you will need to set the appropriate local or group policy setting so it becomes "Managed by your administrator" and becomes greyed out. The registry key only stops the nagging popup.

Comment: Can I set group policy via command line using a script ? If that is possible I can add it to my script .

Comment: Not easily out of the box, I'm afraid. I linked to a Powershell module in my answer that might be able to help you out, but I've never used it myself. Why can't you just use a domain policy, or if you're not on a domain, bake the local policy setting into your Windows image?

Comment: I am new to powershell , so not completely aware of the available options. The vm is not in domain. So i am trying to configure the windows and then will create an image using image capture wizard by running sccm.

Comment: You are working against windows and how its tools for deployment are designed. I don't know the intricacies of how SCCM creates an image, but generally when creating a system image it doesn't matter how you set the reference machine settings as long as they are set. For local policies, when sysprepping an image there are additional steps to take to retain those settings during image generalization, but not sure if SCCM would retain the reference machine policy when creating an image. If the image is going to be used to create a domain-joined computer, you should just set this in group policy.

Comment: It is generally best to create as clean an image as possible and set any settings you can after the image has been deployed.